# Selecting a tag and class (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I the following:

```
<div id = "thisOne">
<a href = "#" class="ui-state-highlight">abc</a>
<a href = "#'>def</a>
</div>
```

If i do $(".thisOne a") I get both "a" elements. I just want the one that is highlighted, how do I do this?

Comment: I'm going to assume to meant to grab the `thisOne` by ID selector and not class....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This two lines of code should help you, give them a try :

```
$("#thisOne .highlight")
```

and for the other

```
$("#thisOne :not(.highlight)")
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried that but it wasn't giving me anything...I realized that instead of "highlight" as the class it was "ui-state-hightlight". Does that make a difference?

Comment: of course that makes a difference. change .highlight in rlemon's post to .ui-state-highlight. and please do some jQuery tutorials. this is the most basic you can get with jQuery.

Comment: @JZ11, listen to Jack. also ***Please Read the Documents*** http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Okay sorry I wasn't clear. I know it makes a difference, and I obviously used "ui-state-hightlight" instead of highlight. Sorry I wasn't clear. But it's not working.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I probably shouldn't have simplified the html so much, but there are 3 more levels of tags in between "thisOne" and the highlighted a element. Thanks for help and sorry for confusion.

Comment: alternatively you can use `.find()` or `.children()` *although I have never liked using the children() selector... never works as I expect it to* or additional checks like `$("#thisOne a").filter(".ui-state-default")` *I think filter would be inefficient in this case.. but it's there*

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: `$('a.highlight');`

Comment: Looking at the way the OP had formatted the content I would assume `thisOne` would also have a sibling `thatOne` presumably with anchor tags in it..